# Java: find every unique word in a list and add them to a new list

Tags: java, list, for-loop

I'm trying to create a method that finds every unique word in a list and then adds them to a new list. I have tried the following:

```
   public static void countWords(){
   List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
   List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

   String inText = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type in text");
   int start = 0;    

     for(int i = 0; i < inText.length(); i++) {
        if(inText.charAt(i) == ' ') {
           list1.add(inText.substring(start,i));
           start = i;
        }                           
     }
        for(int a = 0; a < list1.size(); a++) {
           for(int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
              if(list1.get(a) != list2.get(j)) {
                 list2.add(list2.get(a));                 
              }               
           }           
        }         
}
```

When I run the program and type in "hi hi hi" I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
at RäknaOrd.countWords(RäknaOrd.java:24)
at RäknaOrd.main(RäknaOrd.java:6)
```

How could I fix this error? Would my approach even work?

Comment: A better approach would be to split based on `\\s+` (i.e, space(s)) and then use method like `contains()` of `List` and add words to the List

Comment: it is more efficient to use a `Set` for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java 8 has a nice stream based method to return a new list with duplicates removed :

```
List<String> list2 = list1.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Also to split the `String` and get a `List<String>` you can avoid a for loop like this :

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(inText.split(" "));
```

But keep in mind that `list1` is immutable in this case.

A minimal example for demonstration would be :

```
String inText = "hi hi hi";
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(inText.split(" "));
List<String> list2 = list1.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list2);
```

Which prints `[hi]`

Comment: When I try this the program says: cannot find symbol Collectors.toList. Do I need to import something for this to work properly?

Comment: `import java.util.stream.Collectors;`

Comment: I tried what you said and tested: ´List<String> list2 = list1.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());´but when i run the program with input "hi hi hi" and then print list2 i get the ouput "hi, hi" like there is a duplicate still in the list...

Comment: @samtob I added a simple example in my answer as it's too much for a comment. I put these lines in a `main` method and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here  `if(list1.get(a) != list2.get(j))`

`list2` is empty and you are trying to access elements in it by `list2.get(j)`

so instead write `!list2.contains(list1.get(a))`

```
for(int a = 0; a < list1.size(); a++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
         if(!list2.contains(list1.get(a))) {
           list2.add(list1.get(a));                 
        }               
     }           
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `Set` to detect doubles is more efficient. A `Set` does not allow multiple copies of the same object to be present. Furthermore, a `Set` can detect whether an item is already contained in the set in log(n) time (i.e. it does not have to iterate over all n elements inside the set).

**Code:**

```
public static List<String> unique(List<String> list) {
    Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>();
    for(String word : list)
        unique.add(word);
    return new ArrayList<String>(unique);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> test=new ArrayList<String>();
    test.add("hi");
    test.add("test");
    test.add("hi");
    System.out.println(unique(test));

}
```

**Output:**

```
[test, hi]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe using a Stream might be a good solution:

```
list2=list1.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    String paragraph = "I felt happy because I saw the others were happy.";

    String words[]=paragraph.split("\\W+");
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
    {
      if(list2.contains(words[i])==false)
      {
         list2.add(words[i]);
      }
      else {
         list1.add(words[i]);
      }
    }
    list2.removeAll(list1);
    Collections.sort(list2);
    System.out.print(list2);
}
```

output:

```
[because, felt, others, saw, the, were]
```